# Why Stream.send() send the message AFTER the timeout?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ip, wifi

I have a program which open a tcp connection, send a message and receive a message after few seconds using the ManagedWifi API in C# on Visual Studio Express 2013. On my last computer (RIP), the code worked perfectly.

```
private void sendTCPstr(string message_str, string ip_addr, int port)
{
IPAddress basewifi_addr_ip = IPAddress.Parse(ip_addr);
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
tcp.SendTimeout = 5000;
tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
stream = tcp.GetStream();
stream.Write(message_byte, 0, message_byte.Length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
int i = 0;
i = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
tcp.Close();
}
```

It appears that here, my message is sent AFTER the timeout (after 5 sec), instead of sending the message and then wait for 5 sec if there's any ACK, verified with wireshark and logfiles. I changed nothing in this code, just the computer. Those functions worked well on my last computer, even timeouts. I correctly change the paths of my assemblies. The rest of the code works perfectly.

My ex computer:
laptop ACER 64bits
Wifi integrated
Windows 10

My actual computer:
Sud-tech tower (French) 64bits
Wifi with a D-Link adapter
Windows 10

Have you ever encounter this problem? How can I solve it?
I have no idea what to do more, and I need to use those functions in my program.

edit: It says that the connection cannot be established or the host cannot respond in time, but I saw on wireshark that the connection is established and the host cannot ack in less than 5 sec because my computer send the message after 5sec.

Edit2:
It seems that it was stream.Read() which caused the problem. When I only write on the stream, the program works. But now, I cannot read the stream anymore, while on my old computer it worked perfectly... and error keeps saying that there were a timeout error.

Comment: maybe you need to call Flush so the buffer gets send, despite not having reached its threshold.

Comment: agreed; I'd try adding a `stream.Flush();` after the `.Write()` - personally I prefer using the `Socket.NoDelay` flag and dealing with buffering upstream, but: that's just an opinion

Comment: Ok, i added stream.Flush(), but there is the same problem. I tried to put the NoDelay flag, but it changed nothing.